# How do I unserialize this?

Tags: php

I don't know the most about WordPress, but I see some serialized data in the DB that a plugin creates. The plugin works just fine, so I guess it unserializes it just fine too.

When *I* try to unserialize() it, it fails and var_dump shows bool(false) for the result.

This is the string I see in the database:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"name";s:56:"Song → Black Meen : “So Clean (feat. Dullaah Jin)”";s:4:"file";s:98:"http://localhost/peace.worldwide/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/03-So-Clean-feat.-Dullaah-Jin.mp3";s:9:"condition";s:3:"all";}}
```

You might notice that the length fields don't match with the lengths of the values in the quotes.

What's going on here? How do I unserialize this data?

Comment: Where is this data and how are you retrieving it? You should never have to unserialize anything, the API does it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct serialized string will be:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"name";s:56:"Song → Black Meen : “So Clean (feat. Dullaah Jin)”";s:4:"file";s:93:"http://localhost/peace.worldwide/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/03-So-Clean-feat.-Dullaah-Jin.mp3";s:9:"condition";s:3:"all";}}
```

The second long string ( value of key "file" ) had incorrect lenght 98 which should be 93. You might ask why the first long string ( value of key "name" ) has lenght of 56. It looks like it should be 50. This string contains three special characters ( → “ and ” ) and their lenghts are 3 each therefore final length is 50 + ( 3 * 2 ) = 56.

Comment: It looks like the serialized string in database was edited by hand

Comment: There's something going on here. None of the serialized strings were edited by hand, however they do contain abnormal characters like arrow, quotes, and colons. I'm thinking that maybe the data is stored differently (with the correct lengths) but when I view it (and copy and paste it) it comes out different.

I'm using the Easy Digital Downloads plugin, which is creating these serialized strings. The plugin works perfect. I don't quite understand how it works perfect, but it does. Unfortunately for me, simply doing unserialize() on the string doesn't work (obviously).

Comment: Oh, so is there a way to handle special chars before unserialize() or something?

Comment: oooooh! I see. OK, so when I migrated from str8wayent.com to localhost (for testing) by search/replacing the whole DB, it messed up the counts.... So my question now is: How is it that the Easy Digital Downloads plugin continues to work?? hmmm... I guess what I need to do is just make new test data specifically for localhost.

Comment: Wow, things get messy. Now I fear that other sites I've migrated from one domain to another might have serialized strings that are now invalid. Any suggestion on how to fix this seemingly horrid problem?

Comment: Aha, I found a script that fixes the lengths. Let's see if it works: https://github.com/Blogestudio/Fix-Serialization

Comment: Sweeeeeet. It worked. This is a *great* tool to have.